# vb.net. SQL SUM and Between, can't sum value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i use this syntax to SUM some data between id.. but it's only select the value of last id..

i have tables with 3 fied,, there are id, arrival, departure, and distance..

here is the syntax:

```
SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(CAST(distance AS Numeric(10, 0))) FROM route WHERE id BETWEEN  " & s & "  AND  " & w & "", SQLCon)
    Dim r As SqlDataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader

    r.Read()
    distance2 = r(0).ToString
```

s and w is an integer

so i show the value of distance on textbox1.text = distance2..

the problem is, the value isn't the SUM of that Query,, but the value of textbox1.text is the falue of "w"
the query on sqlserver is work, i replace s and w to 1 and 3, but when i use on VB.net it is not work..

anyone can help ?

Comment: If anyone ever enters `; DROP TABLE route;` into the UI supplying the value for `s`, someone is going to have a very bad day.  Look into parameterized queries.

Comment: sorry ..what you mean ?

Comment: Your SQL is subject to a vulnerability called SQL Injection.  If someone enters certain values for your parameter `s`, they can drop tables in your database, query data they should not, and do all sorts of other nasty things.  Parameterized queries protect you from that type of issue.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest that where you have

```
... " & s & "  AND  " & w & "...
```

you need to have

```
... " + s.ToString() + "  AND  " + w.ToString() + " ...
```

Otherwise the & operator will not perform string concatenation, but rather type conversion. The rules for this are arcane (have a look [here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Evil_Type_Coercion.htm) for a primer).

Comment: You are incorrect. Your first line works correctly. & is the correct way to concat in VB.NET. I think you may be getting confused with the Vb6 behaviour which the article you linked to is talking about